# How to control number of parameters into a function and dataframe

Tags: r, parameters, parameter-passing

I want to build a function based on the given input value of n. For example, I want to have n variables for that function. Inside the function, I want to build a dataframe based on the number of parameters available from that function (in this case, it is n). For example,

```
n = 3
Build <- function(a1,a2,a3){
parameters = data.frame(a1=a1, a2=a2, a3=a3)
}
```

or

```
n = 6
Build <- function(a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6){
parameters = data.frame(a1=a1, a2=a2, a3=a3, a4=a4, a5=a5, a6=a6)
}
```

The input is n, where a1,a2,...,an is to be assigned a value between 0 and 1. It is easy if I want to do it one by one. But how to automate this process?

Comment: The input isn't clear. Are `a1`, ..., `a6` vectors in your global environment?

Comment: @Roland , it will be  used to input values between 0 and 1.

Comment: You have not answered my request for clarification.

Comment: @Roland , no it's not a vector. It's float type.

Comment: There is not floating point values in R that are not part of a vector. The question still is: "How are the ai values defined? Where do they come from?"

Answer (score 0):

`...` handles unknown arguments

```
Build <- function(...){
  parameters <- data.frame(...)
  return(parameters)
}
```

Result:

```
Build(a=c(1,3,4),b=c(2,3,3))
  a b
1 1 2
2 3 3
3 4 3
```